# Playback device missing on startup in Ubuntu Studio 21.10

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

Weird issue recently popped up, every time I start up my laptop the playback devices are missing from the list of sound devices and presumably don't work (haven't gotten the chance to test it yet). I can get them to show up after I plug something into the headphone jack, but I want a fix, not a workaround. I can't think of anything that's causing this, since it sort of just started happening.

Running Ubuntu Studio 21.10.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and describe *how* you've come to the conclusion that your "the playback devices are missing", post your hardware specifications, particularly which "playback" device(s) is/are missing.

Comment: I'm not too well versed in sound hardware, it's whatever comes with an Acer Aspire A315-56. I mean to say that they're missing in the list of sound devices and don't work until I plug something in. Will edit the question accordingly.